# ¿Cómo usar regex para sacar un nombre entre espacios en mi fichero de texto?

Tags: python, regex

Tengo un texto bastante largo con nombres de datos etc. Los datos digamos que serían así:

```
[espacios]Elnombre1[espacios](237) 
[espacios]Elnombre3(237) 
[espacios]Elnombre4(17)
```

Necesito sacar solamente los nombres. Normalmente los nombres van con espacios antes y después del nombre, y por último paréntesis y dentro un número.

Además, necesito añadir algún texto entre paréntesis (sirve cualquier texto).

Resultado esperado:

> ```
> nombremio123textoquepuse(losparentesis)
> ```

Intenté con:

```
with open("e.txt", 'r+') as f:
    texto = re.sub('^\s+([a-zA-Z-0-9]+)\s*', f.read())
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(texto)
    f.truncate()
```

¿Alguna manera posible de hacerlo leyendo un fichero de texto y reescribiéndolo con los datos correctos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una idea. Parte la línea por el paréntesis y después haz un `strip` del primer elemento, para eliminarle los espacios que pueda tener al inicio y al final. Es decir:

```py
lineas = [
  '   Elnombre1     (237)',
  '      Elnombre3(237)',
  '    Elnombre4(17)' 
  ]

nombres = []

for linea in lineas:
    nombre = linea.split('(')[0].strip()
    nombres.append(nombre)

print(nombres)
```

Sale

> `['Elnombre1', 'Elnombre3', 'Elnombre4']`

### Actualización

Para trabajar sobre fichero, si la cantidad de líneas no es enorme, un enfoque sería, leerlo primero, procesando las líneas y acumulando los resultados en en una lista, y escribirlo después.

```py
nombres = []
with open("e.txt", "r") as f:
   for linea in f:
     nombre = linea.split('(')[0].strip()
     nombres.append(nombre)
with open("e.txt", "w") as f:  # Cuidado! Sobreescribiendo fichero
   for nombre in nombres:
     f.write("{}\n".format(nombre))
```

El inconveniente de este enfoque es que tienes que tener en memoria los resultados antes de escribirlos. Esto no debería ser problema a menos que el fichero sea monstruoso, pero si fuera un problema entonces sería mejor abrir dos ficheros (el original para lectura y el de resultados para escritura) e ir escribiendo las líneas a medida que se procesan en lugar de almacenarlas en una lista. Al final, una vez cerrados los ficheros, podrías renombrar el de salida y darle el mismo nombre que a la entrada.

### Actualización 2

En una edición posterior de la pregunta, se pide la posibilidad de extraer lo que va en los paréntesis y añadir texto extra (entiendo que prefijado).

Para este tipo de procesamiento empieza a ser prefereible armar una expresión regular que capture las diferentes partes de la línea que interesan. No obstante las expresiones regulares [como es sabido](https://www.meneame.net/c/7840380) son un tema delicado, y además ya hay otra respuesta que muestra cómo usarlas, de modo que mostraré aquí la solución "artesanal" (aunque no es la recomendaría en general).

Para extraer lo que hay dentro del paréntesis, podemos aprovechar que ya hemos partido la línea por el `(`, por lo que en el elemento `[1]` estará el resto de la línea. Basta eliminar el último carácter (que será el `)`) para obtener lo que iba dentro de los paréntesis. Es decir:

```py
lineas = [
  '   Elnombre1     (237)',
  '      Elnombre3(225)',
  '    Elnombre4(17)' 
  ]

texto_prefijado = "textoquepuse"
nombres = []

for linea in lineas:
    trozos = linea.split('(')
    nombre = trozos[0].strip()
    numero = trozos[1][:-1] 
    nombres.append("{}{}{}".format(nombre, texto_prefijado, numero))

print(nombres)
```

> `['Elnombre1textoquepuse237', 'Elnombre3textoquepuse225', 'Elnombre4textoquepuse17']`

Comment: una pregunta si quisiera añadir los paréntesis porque en esta ocasión tengo informacion relevante es decir como has hecho precisamente pero a parte se podría hacer para que escribiese los parentesis mas lo que hay dentro lo escribiese? ej. mis datos (lo que pusistes) + "algun texto mio"+ (el contenido de los parentesis) seria posible y disculpa por las molestias! ya edite mi pregunta disculpar de nuevo es la ultima modificacion!

Comment: @SergioRamos Respuesta actualizada, comprueba que es lo que necesitas

Comment: en un fichero de texto me devuelve `line 13, in <module>
    numero = trozos[1][:-1]
IndexError: list index out of range` supongo que será porque hay saltos de linea que estan vacios?

Comment: @SergioRamos Eso es que ha llegado a una línea que no tiene el carácter `(` y por tanto el resultado de `split('(')` no da dos elementos. Podrías incluir tras el `split()` un `if len(trozos)<2: continue`, para que se salte ese tipo de líneas

Comment: una ultima duda si hay espacios entre el nombre, me da exactamente lo que pido pero sería posible además una vez sacadas las palabras después convertir los espacios que hay entre los nombres ejemplo mariano jose en guiones bajos? ej. mario perez -> mario_perez. una vez sacado los nombres tal como dijistes sería posible además hacer esto intente chekeando los subs como hicistes tu o usando replace pero no fue ! disculpame mucho es la ultima duda que tenia la respuesta esta completada pero si puedieras aclarar esa pequeña duda , gracias!

Comment: @SergioRamos No sé qué habrás intentado con `replace`, pero la cosa es tan simple como añadir `nombre = nombre.replace(" ", "_")` después de extraer el nombre.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de lograr obtener el nombre utilizando una expresión regular pude ser la siguiente:

```
  import re

  lineas = [
  '    Elnombre1     (237)',
  '    Elnombre3(237)',
  '    Elnombre4(17)' 
  ]

  nombres = [re.findall('^\s+([a-zA-Z-0-9]+)\s*', x)[0] for x in lineas]

  print(nombres)
```

Salida final:

> ['Elnombre1', 'Elnombre3', 'Elnombre4']

#### Explicación

La expresión regular `^\s+([a-zA-Z-0-9]+)\s*` lo que hace es buscar que se inicie con un caracter de espacio `\s` al menos una vez, continue con letras o números (los parentesis () permite hacer la captura del nombre) y a este le siga nuevamente cero o más carcater `*` de espacio `\s`.

Referencias

- [Grupos de captura](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Tipos de caracteres genéricos](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- [Clases carácter](http://Shorthand%20Character%20Classes)
- [Cuantificadores](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: no sobra un guion entre `A-Z` y `0-9`? Con ese guión, estas aceptando guiones en la busqueda (que podría ser válido pero el OP no lo ha confirmado)

Comment: Y fijate que el autor aclaró la pregunta pidiendo que se agregue un texto luego de capturar.

Answer (score 2):

**Reemplazar capturando una parte del texto**

Teniendo como ejemplo:

```
texto = "        El nombre 1         (237)"
```

Entonces, desde el inicio del texto `^`, espacios opcionales  `*`, cualquier cantidad de caracteres `.*?`, espacios opcionales, los paréntesis con el número `\(\d+\)` y el fin del texto `$`.

- Utilicé `.*?` con el `?` al final para indicarle que coincida con "lo menos posible". Esto es un cuantificador no goloso (*lazy*). Y de esta forma, hace que no consuma los espacios que están después del nombre.
- En esa misma construcción usé un punto (`.`), que coincide con cualquier caracter excepto un salto de línea, pero perfectamente podrías limitarlo a lo que quieras, por ejemplo:
  `[\w .,;!áéíóúüñ]*?`, o cualquier caracter excepto espacios `[^ ]*?`, etc.

Lo que vamos a hacer es **capturar** al nombre. Cuando en una expresión regular se usan paréntesis, el texto con el que coincidió es *capturado* y guardado, por lo que se puede utilizar ese texto en el reemplazo, usando `\1`.

Regex:

```
^ *(.*?) *\(\d+\)$
```

Reemplazo:

```
\1(otrotexto)
```

- Tener en cuenta: `otrotexto` no debería tener `\`s (o deberías escaparlas como `\\`).

Código:

```python
import re

texto = "        El nombre 1         (237)"
entre_parentesis = "otrotexto"

regex = r"^ *(.*?) *\(\d+\)$"
subst = r"\1(" + entre_parentesis +  r")"


resultado = re.sub(regex, subst, texto)

if resultado:
    print (resultado)
```

Resultado:

```
El nombre 1(otrotexto)
```

Demo:

https://ideone.com/s16Wrx

---

**Reemplazar los espacios internos por `_`**

Para convertir `"El nombre 1 (237)"` en `"El_nombre_1(otrotexto)"` usamos una función como parámetro de re.sub(). Usemos un lambda.

```
import re

texto = "El nombre 1 (237)"
sep   = "_"
subst = "(otrotexto)"
regex = r" *(?:\(\d+\)$|([^ ]+))"


texto = re.sub(
           regex,
           lambda m: (sep if m.start() else "") + m.group(1) if m.group(1) else subst,
           texto
        )

print (texto)
```

```
El_nombre_1(otrotexto)
```